# Android Webview: start scrolled to a point on a page

Tags: android, webview, scroll

I want to auto-scroll my webview to a percentage, let's say 3/4th of the page, at the start.

Problem: computeVerticalScrollRange is only known when the webview finished rendering. I do not know (and investigated: i cannot know?) when the webview finished rendering (not loading, but rendering everything), when the size (computeVerticalScrollRange) will be completely final.

What does not work:

1. WebViewClient.onPageFinished is called when computeVerticalScrollRange still returns 0.
2. WebChromeClient.onProgressChanged 100% is called when computeVerticalScrollRange still returns 0.
3. PictureListener.onNewPicture is sometimes called too early, when computeVerticalScrollRange is not final yet (smaller than what it is a second later).
4. Editting the HTML, putting a Javascript handler on window.onload that is calling to the Android class (using an alert) has the same problem: computeVerticalScrollRange is sometimes not final yet (smaller than what it is a second later).

Is there a way to start at (scroll point) 3/4th of a web page?

Comment: why can you just set an anchor in html and add that anchor to the webview url? mypage.net/mysite.html#myanchor

Comment: because the data is not static, and I won't know what exactly 3/4th of the page is before I load it into my webview (I can parse the html but I won't know the size of the images/fonts (and with that the 3/4th point to scroll to) before rendering)

Answer (score 1):

I implemented the **horrible** solution of checking every 600 ms (after the first PictureListener.onNewPicture) if the computeVerticalScrollRange changed. If this content size  did not change in the last 600 ms, I am assuming the web page finishes loading and I do the scroll and show the webview on screen (make it visible).

Horrible: This slows down EVERY page load with 600ms, even for pages with only a few lines.

Horrible: For a very large page 600 ms might not be enough and my app will still not scroll.

I am still looking for a good solution.

Comment: this is what I have done also - but using a linear backoff as most time returns < 1 sec but occasionally over. Note I found an issue where you cant set the initial height of a Webview to 0px and then load and measure content as ~1/10 of the time it will always return 0px. Down with webview! The only good solution IMHO is not having custom logic with webview heights and no webviews in ListViews

Answer (score 0):

What I've done is create a custom `WebView` which has a public method for `computeVerticalScrollRange()`:

```
public int getVerticalScrollRange() {
    return super.computeVerticalScrollRange();
}
```

After that in the `onPageFinished()` call this method:

```
private void computeWebViewHeight() {
    infoWebView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int webViewHeight = customWebView.getVerticalScrollRange();
            // Also have a retryCount max so in case the webView really has a height of 0 you don't have an infinite loop
            if(webViewHeight <= 0 && webViewHeightRetryCount < 10) {
                webViewHeightRetryCount++;
                computeWebViewHeight();
            } else {
                if(webViewHeightRetryCount >= 10) {
                    // RetryCount was above max, so execute fallback
                } else {
                    // WebView has a height, do something with it
                }
                webViewHeightRetryCount = 0;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This way you don't have the delay of 600ms.

I've set the retryCount on 10, but it might be a bit low, I'm not really sure.